Microsoft ESlint 3.0.10 Extension reporting missing config files on Visual Studio Code for Mac
I added the Microsoft ESLint extension into Visual Studio Codw for use with my Javascript project, and I am getting these kind of errors:
Error - 7:27:26 PM] Calculating config file for file:///Users/USER/Desktop/Univ%20of%20Michigan%20Course/Preview%20Mode/Sprint3-single%20player-preview-r2/Track3DroneData.js) failed.
Error: Could not find config file.
at assertConfigurationExists (/Users/USER/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-loader.js:84:23)
at LegacyConfigLoader.loadConfigArrayForFile (/Users/USER/node_modules/eslint/lib/config/config-loader.js:341:9)
at async ESLint.calculateConfigForFile (/Users/USER/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint.js:1060:25)
at async ESLint.isPathIgnored (/Users/USER/node_modules/eslint/lib/eslint/eslint.js:1099:24)
at async /Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:23757
at async Object.M [as withClass] (/Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:19807)
at async t.workspace.getConfiguration.then.O.then.m.validate (/Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:23728)
at async /Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:234417
at async /Users/USER/.vscode/extensions/dbaeumer.vscode-eslint-3.0.10/server/out/eslintServer.js:1:63886
Does anyone have any ideas how to fix this?
Thanks!!!

It looks like you're missing a ESlint configuration file.
You need to create one in the project root.
There are instructions in the eslint docs on how to do that: https://eslint.org/docs/latest/use/configure/configuration-files

Would you know what option I would need to put in that file for ESLint to detect unused functions across the entire project?

https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-expressions
https://eslint.org/docs/latest/rules/no-unused-vars
